# PyGame. Спрайт не поворачивается, при использовании функции pygame.transform.rotate()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Я пишу игру по типу шутера с видом сверху, код будет ниже. Проблема в том, что при использовании функции pygame.transform.rotate(), при повороте ствола, ничего не происходит, с помощью тестов я понял, что функции эти активируются, но реакции ноль. Нет ни ошибок, ничего. [Здесь код игрушки и спрайты.](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13PYZVYKTtzP7RuRIq7qAzaXuo0KOEWuk?usp=sharing) А для тех, кто не хочет ничего скачивать, вот код:

```
import pygame
import sys
import math

# -------------Window settings-------------

pygame.init()
win_dim = (960, 720)
print(win_dim[0] - 5)
win = pygame.display.set_mode(win_dim)
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")

# -------------Sprite settings-------------

character = pygame.image.load("sprites/soldiers/main_character/main.png")
rifle = pygame.image.load("sprites/weapons/rifle.png")
bg = pygame.image.load("sprites/locations/training.png")

# -------------Main character settings-------------

x = 50
y = 50
width = 20
height = 30

stSpeed = 10
speed = 10

# -------------General border settings-------------

borders_x_min = 15
borders_x_max = win_dim[0] - 40
borders_y_min = 15
borders_y_max = win_dim[1] - 40


def reduction(num):
    ostNum = num % 1
    if ostNum < 0.5:
        num = num - ostNum
    elif ostNum >= 0.5:
        num = num + 1 - ostNum
    return num


def cosBetweenVectors(pos1, pos2):
    x1, y1 = pos1[0], pos1[1]
    x2, y2 = pos2[0], pos2[1]
    module1 = reduction(math.sqrt(x1 ** 2 + y1 ** 2))
    module2 = reduction(math.sqrt(x2 ** 2 + y2 ** 2))
    try:
        return (x1 * x2 + y1 * y2) / (module1 * module2)
    except:
        return 0


class Character:
    pos = [x, y]
    vector = [0, 1]
    angle = 180

    def __init__(self, side, type, speed):
        self.side = side
        self.type = type
        self.speed = speed
        self.weaponPos = [self.pos[0] + 65 // 2, self.pos[1]]

    def isMove(self):
        if keys[pygame.K_a] and mc.pos[0] > borders_x_min:  # left
            self.pos[0] -= self.speed
            self.weaponPos[0] -= self.speed
        elif keys[pygame.K_d] and self.pos[0] < borders_x_max - width:  # right
            self.pos[0] += self.speed
            self.weaponPos[0] += self.speed
        if keys[pygame.K_w] and self.pos[1] > borders_y_min:  # up
            self.pos[1] -= self.speed
            self.weaponPos[1] -= self.speed
        elif keys[pygame.K_s] and self.pos[1] < borders_y_max - height:  # down
            self.pos[1] += self.speed
            self.weaponPos[1] += self.speed

    def aim(self):
        if pygame.mouse.get_focused():
            pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            vectorToMouse = [pos[0] - (self.pos[0] + 65 // 2), pos[1] - self.pos[1]]
            angleInRad = math.acos(cosBetweenVectors(self.vector, vectorToMouse))
            angle = reduction(math.degrees(angleInRad))
            self.angle = 0
            self.angle = angle
            if pos[0] > self.pos[0] + 65 // 2:
                print("moved")
                pygame.transform.rotate(rifle, self.angle)
            elif pos[0] < self.pos[0] + 65 // 2:
                self.angle = 360 - self.angle
                pygame.transform.rotate(rifle, self.angle)
            else:
                pygame.transform.rotate(rifle, self.angle)
            print(self.angle)

    def shoot(self):
        pass


mc = Character("friendly", "solider", speed)
while True:
    pygame.time.delay(100)
    win.fill((0, 128, 128))
    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    mc.isMove()
    mc.aim()
    win.blit(rifle, (mc.weaponPos[0], mc.weaponPos[1]))
    win.blit(character, (mc.pos[0], mc.pos[1]))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
    if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
        sys.exit()
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE] and keys[pygame.K_p]:
        speed += 50
    pygame.display.update()


sys.exit()
```

Код подписан комментариями далеко не везде, так что буду готов ответить на вопросы. Надеюсь на помощь, заранее спасибо.

Comment: В некоторых местах разбросаны функции print(). Они нужны там для некоторых тестов, так что прошу не задавать вопросы о них.

Answer (score 0):

В справке функция описана так

pygame.transform.rotate()
rotate an image
rotate(Surface, angle) -> Surface

то есть возвращает новый surface, нужно заменять тот что есть

Comment: Ну, я это сделал, ствол начал двигаться... но как-то неправильно... Вот примерно вот так.. https://youtu.be/BMwDUzoAYlw

Comment: А если продержать его достаточное кол-во времени, то он выдаст следующую ошибку `pygame.error: Out of memory`